# Matching Sift Features on Three Images using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

The goal is to match more than 2 images using Python and (not a must) OpenCV. Three images would be good enough at first.
Is there a general approach how to do this? Currently, I am matching 1->2 and 2->3 using SIFT and the following code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('picture1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('picture2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img3 = cv2.imread('picture3.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

#-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SIFT Detector, compute the descriptors
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute( img1, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute( img2, None)
keypoints3, descriptors3 = sift.detectAndCompute( img3, None)

#-- Step 2: Matching descriptor vectors with a FLANN based matcher for image pair 1 -> 2 

matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DescriptorMatcher_FLANNBASED)
knn_matches1_2 = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, 2)
#-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
ratio_thresh = 0.4
good_matches1_2 = []
for m,n in knn_matches1_2:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches1_2.append(m)

#-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors with a FLANN based matcher for image pair 2 -> 3 

knn_matches2_3 = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors2, descriptors3, 2)

#-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
ratio_thresh = 0.4
good_matches2_3 = []
for m,n in knn_matches2_3:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches2_3.append(m)
```

This leaves me with `goodmatches1_2` and `goodmatches2_3` containing the matches from image 1->2 and 2->3. So is there any method to match 1->2->3, so only the corresponding points of three images?
Any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and here's how I deal with it, but I think there should be a better approach:

To my knowledge SIFT points of a image will always be the same, that is, of all pairs in `goodmatches1_2 = [[sift1, sift2], ...]` and `goodmatches2_3 = [[sift2, sift3], ...]` there should be at least some match where `sift2` from these two lists will be exactly the same. So I just do:

```
goodmatches123 = []
for i, sift12 in enumerate(goodmatches1_2):
    for j, sift23 in enumerate(goodmatches2_3):
        if sift12 == sift23:
            goodmatches123.append(goodmatches1_2[i],sift12,goodmatches2_3[j])
```

Hope that gives you some inspiration!